# Set redirect in .htaccess for all the urls with a suffix

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the urls like:

```
example.com/vm-search/parentcategory-cityname/childcategory-cityname
```

They are indexed by search engines. I decided to remove the cityname suffix from all the parentcategories and now I need to set redirect from all the old urls to new ones before the search engines will index them. The citynames are the same for all the urls and the new urls will be like:

```
example.com/vm-search/parentcategory/childcategory-cityname
```

I haven't try anything with htaccess yet. What rule should I add to the file?

Comment: What is the new URL and show your attempts also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(vm-search/.+?)/results,\d+-\d+$ /$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(vm-search/(?:[^/-]+/)*[^/-]+)-[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Let me see if I can come up with a regex for deeper level URLs. Give me few minutes for trials.

Comment: You can replace above rule by this: `RewriteRule ^(vm-search/(?:[^/-]+/)*[^/-]+)-[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]` and it will remove all `-cityname/` from everywhere except the last one.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you again. The urls are being generated for Virtuemart categories and a moment ago I've noticed one more problem with them. If a user goes to the next page of the same category the following end is being added to the url: `/results,9-10` Can you rewrite your rule so if the url has `/vm-search/...-city/results,9-10` the rule removes all the cities except the last one and remaining `/results,9-10` (digits may be any number from 0 to N). Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, digits may be any number from 0 to N (e.g. 9-10, 40-80, 800-900 and so on) and `results,` is always a static text

Comment: If I use both rules and try to go to the next page (that has `results` in the url) I can't go to this page

Comment: ok then I as I suggested please open a new question so that it can be answered in entirety not as an addendum.