# Set redirect in .htaccess if url has a suffix and can have an end

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On the Virtuemart website of my client category pages have urls like:

```
example.com/vm-search/level1category-cityname/level2category-cityname
or
example.com/vm-search/level1category-cityname/level2category-cityname/level3category-cityname
or
example.com/vm-search/.../-cityname/result,9-10 (digits may be any numbers from 1 to N)
```

I need a redirect rule for .htaccess that would remove all the citynames on the fly except the last city and remaining also `result,9-10` if it's the end of the url i.e. results must be like:

```
example.com/vm-search/level1category/level2category-cityname
or
example.com/vm-search/level1category/level2category/level3category-cityname
or
example.com/vm-search/level1category/level2category-cityname/result,9-10 (digits may be any numbers from 1 to N)
or
example.com/vm-search/level1category/level2category/level3category-cityname/result,9-10 (digits may be any numbers from 1 to N)
```

Please don't view the question as duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/q/30298289/3208225](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30298289/3208225) for it has another conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(vm-search)/(?:([^-]+)-[^/]+/)+?([^/-]+-(?=[a-z])[^/]+(?:/.*)?)$ /$1/$2/$3 [L,NC,R=302]
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to **avoid multiple redirects** then use env variable like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(vm-search)/(?:([^-]+)-[^/]+/)+?([^/-]+-(?=[a-z])[^/]+(?:/.*)?)$ /$1/$2/$3 [NC,L,E=IS_REDIR:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_IS_REDIR} =1
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match and replace with nothing (empty string):

```
-cityname(?=.*cityname)
```

Something like the following (check for syntax):

```
Rewrite -cityname(?=.*cityname) [L,NC,R=302]
```

If you want to have generic keywords.. use the following:

```
-([^\/\s]+)(?=.*-\1)
```

Comment: I believe `cityname` is not a static text here.

Comment: If use `Rewrite -cityname(?=.*cityname) [L,NC,R=302]` or `Rewrite -([^\/\s]+)(?=.*-\1) [L,NC,R=302]` I get the **500 Internal Server Error**

Comment: I have no idea about htaccess syntax.. regex works fine.. maybe @anubhava could help with the syntax?